# How to create table in SQL Server using script code in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

My project is created in WPF and using Entity Framework. I want to create a table in SQL Server using a SQL script.

In our project, the table gets created in the same way, I have to do the same

I try this example #1:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Execute.Sql(@"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Exam]
                  (
                      [exam_id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                      [subject_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
                      [emp_id] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
                      [department_id] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
                      CONSTRAINT [PK_Exam] 
                          PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([exam_id] ASC)
                                  WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                                        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                                        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
                  ) ON [PRIMARY]
                  GO");
}
```

Example #2:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Execute.Sql(@"GO   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Exam] 
                       (
                           [exam_id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                           [subject_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
                           [emp_id] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
                           [department_id] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
                           CONSTRAINT [PK_Exam] 
                               PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([exam_id] ASC)
                                       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                                             IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                                             ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
                       ) ON [PRIMARY]
                       GO");
}
```

Both attempts are almost the same - the difference is the first word `GO` in example #2

I tried to run both versions - but neither created the table.

Instead, the code throws this exception:

> The table name is not valid. [ Token line number (if known) = 1,Token line offset (if known) = 22,Table name = Exam ]"}
> System.Exception {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException}

What is the mistake in my code?

Please help

Comment: You seem to be using a ***SQL Server CE*** database connection ... `System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException` - that's not going to work for a "real" SQL Server database and table. Also: **drop** the `GO` - that's **NOT** a valid SQL statement and utterly unnecessary!

Comment: @marc_s plz put update code because I am new in WPF

Comment: That has **nothing** to do with WPF - but you didn't show anything I could update ....... how are you configuring your EF system??

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that using SQL Server CE might have an issue with accepting schemas in SQL queries. Redo create table but minus `[dbo].` I ran into the same issue and found it that you'll get errors inside SQL Server CE both standalone and C# until you remove that "parameter".

Just use Schema for SQL Server only, or don't use at all... seems to be the only answer for now.

I wrote a custom `if (db.Connection is SqlConnection)` then added/omitted schema from query based on whatever database provider was connected. (You'll also need to change data types too, because SQL Server CE doesn't offer full range of data types, like `datetime2` which tracks datetime var with greater precision.